# Instance variables are purged when user fails his authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have trouble getting instances variables while overriding `Devise::SessionsController`.

When an unauthenticated user add an item to its cart, I want to redirect him to the sign in page and apply the addition after he's authenticated.

1 . I pass the `item_id` as a URL parameters:

```
localhost:3000/user_accounts/sign_in?item_id=42
```

2. I get back in a hidden field in the form, I can have it through the session creation form:

```html
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, value: params[:item_id] || @item_id %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

When Rails starts his form flow, the URL parameters are removed:

**Before:**

```
localhost:3000/user_accounts/sign_in?item_id=42
```

**After:**

```
localhost:3000/user_accounts/sign_in
```

I don't want to loose the item_id when the user fails his authentication, so I ensure `@item_id` is exposed as an instance variable, so I can inject it back to the form.

However, on failure, Rails(?) / Devise(?) / Warden(?) seems to purge the instance variables (for security reasons?). As a result, `@item_id` is `nil`.

Note that works well when the user successfully authenticate (through URL parameters). Also, I use this very same technique in the registration process and it works in both success (URL parameters) and failure (instances variables) case.

Here is my implementation of SessionsController:

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    @item_id = parse_id(params[:user_account][:item])
    super do |account|
      add_to_cart(account, @item_id) if @item_id
    end
    flash.delete(:notice)
  end
end
```

Do you know how I can fix this ?

I am open to alternatives as well.

Comment: I would add items to user's cookie. You don't need to pass through all these get parameters.

Comment: cookie, or session, etc… trying to preserve params through multiple redirection is **the** thing you don't want to deal with

Comment: @nattfodd I will try this. I hope Cookies won't be cleared as well as instance variables.

Comment: @Ben This doesn't help me much.

Comment: It was advising (while confirming the previous comment as sessions and cookies can be considered very close in rails), not judging

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. Rails, Devise and Warden aren't doing shady things to my instance variables. I found out that a redirection was made, explaining why the context was lost.

In the end, I used cookies to fix the problem as @nattfodd suggested it. This was trivial I don't know why I didn't think of it.

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    item_id = parse_id(cookies.encrypted[:item])
    super do |account|
      add_to_cart(account, item_id) if item_id
      cookies.encrypted[:item] = ""
    end
    flash.delete(:notice)
  end
end
```

Cleaner, no hack. Good.